# Get Featured Image of Pages - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a loop that gets the title, content, and link of all pages that are a child of the current page.  Everything is working except I don't know how to get the featured image url for these pages so that I can use it as a background image.  You can see in the code where I have commented where I am trying to get the url of the featured image.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $mypages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'sort_order' => 'asc' ) );

     foreach( $mypages as $page ) {     
             $content = $page->post_content;
             if ( ! $content ) // Check for empty page
             continue;

             $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
             $trimmed_content = wp_trim_words( $content, 14, "..." );
             ?>
             <div class="service-box block-grid-item">
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-xs-6 col service-image">


             <!-- This is where I am trying to get the featured image url -->


             <?php $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>
                  <a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>" style="background-image: url(<?php echo '$feat_image'; ?>)"</a>
                   </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col service-body">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>">
                          <span class="service-title"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></span>
                          <span class="service-text"><?php echo $trimmed_content; ?></span>
                          <span class="service-link">Read more</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                 </div>
             </div>

<?php   }   
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but you should be using [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src), and should remove the quotes from your variable when you `echo` the source:

```
$feat_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'large' );
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $page->ID ); ?>" 
   style="background-image: url(<?php echo $feat_image; ?>)">
```

You should also take a look at your HTML markup and make sure it's valid.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply.  I just updated the code in the question and on my site, but it's still returning an empty value for the background url.

Also, thanks for the html markup tips, I inherited this from another dev so that will be phase 2.

Comment: If it's empty, that means there's no featured image associated with that post. Also, are you sure it's actually empty? Given your markup, it's possible that the image is actually being added to the HTML, but that it's not showing because the height of your `<a>` is zero. Unless you've styled this link tag with CSS, the image *shouldn't* be showing. I would inspect the source and add some kind of height to the link tag.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's empty.  I inspected it already, there is CSS attached to it to give it a height, width, etc.  The pages do have featured images associated with them, so I'm not sure why it isn't showing

Comment: After digging a little further, it turns out the featured image was actually a custom field, so once I adjusted the code to reflect that variable it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

on above answer some part of code is missing. here is the complete code.

```
  <?php $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( 5 ), 'large' );
        print_r($feat_image);
     ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( '5' ); ?>" 
       style="background-image: url(<?php echo $feat_image[0]; ?>)"> </a>
```